# PHP/mysql: querying MySQL with an array and getting results in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have an array, $scans. I want to query MySQL with all the values in that array and get my results back in an array. For example, sample data in scans would be:

```
E1234
E2244
E3654
```

The MYSQL table `PARTS` has fields `part, size, length, plate, side, type`.

I want to end up with `$output["E1234"][0]` to be the size result for that part, 1 to be length, etc. and I want the array to be sortable by the MYSQL query. (order by `SIDE desc, PLATE asc`).

Right now, i'm just stepping through the `$SCANS` array and doing query after query, but I'm not able to then sort all the results properly.

Is this possible? This is what I'm doing now, but obviously since each query returns one row which is then outputted, there's no sortability. I want to be able to perform one query, sort the results within the array, and then output that data after the sort.

```
    foreach ($scans as $currentscan) {
        $partselect = substr(mysql_real_escape_string($currentscan), 0, 5);

        $query = "SELECT french, length, plate, side, type FROM parts WHERE part = '$partselect' ORDER BY side DESC, plate ASC LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        #echo 'query is '.$query.'   <br>';
        $error = mysql_error();
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($num_rows == 0) {
            echo 'BAD PART: '.$currentscan.' '.$partselect.' error is '.$error.'<br \>
            ';
        } else {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            print $partselect.' is a '.$row['french'].'/'.$row['length'].' - '.$row['type'].' - '.$row['plate'].'('.$row['side'].')<br \>';
        }
    };
```

EDIT: This is the code as it is now following some suggestions here:

```
$scans = explode("\n",$_POST['scans']);

foreach ($scans as $currentscan) {
   if ($currentscan[0] == "E") { //this is a cheap trick to ignore a bad scan inherent in the scanning mechanism
   $partselect = substr(mysql_real_escape_string($currentscan), 0, 5);
   $tempQuery .= 'part = "'.$partselect.'" OR ';

   };
};//end foreach 
$tempQuery = substr($tempQuery, 0, -3); //remove last OR (fixed substr to 0,-3 to scrip final OR - stephen) 
$tempQuery .= ") ORDER BY side DESC, plate ASC LIMIT 1"; //add on end of query 
$query = "SELECT french, length, plate, side, type FROM parts WHERE ".$tempQuery;
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo $result;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   print $row['french']." / ".$row['length']; //just doing something pointless to verify data was pulled.
}
```

result is:

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/foo/bar/sort.php on line 35

Line 35 is 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

FINAL EDIT:

It works.

```
//DECLARED CONSTANTS//

if (!$_POST) { // Have scans been entered? If not, display the form.
print '
<html>
<body>
Scans:
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<textarea rows="20" cols="6" name="scans" id="scans">
</textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</body>
</html>
';
} else { //Scans have been entered. Start scan processing logic

//==openDB==//
mysql_connect(SQLSERVER, SQLUSER, SQLPASSWORD) or die("Can not connect to DB server.");
mysql_select_db(DATABASE) or die("Can not connect to Database.");
//==openDB==//

$scans = explode("\n",$_POST['scans']); // Explode posted scans into scans array

foreach ($scans as $currentscan) { // step through each scan
   if ($currentscan[0] == "E") { //Cheap check for real part numbers.
   $partselect = substr(mysql_real_escape_string($currentscan), 0, 5); // Strip off the extraneous data from the scan
   $count{$partselect}++; //Count instances of particular parts. ideally this would be in an array in the form of $count[$partnumber] so I can easily display that data at the end. each part needs to be displayed every time it's scanned.
   $tempQuery .= 'part = "'.$partselect.'" OR '; //Starts building query

   };
};//end foreach 
$tempQuery = substr($tempQuery, 0, -3); //remove last OR 

$tempQuery .= ") ORDER BY side DESC, plate ASC"; //add on end of query 
$query = "SELECT part, french, length, plate, side, type FROM parts WHERE (".$tempQuery; //Form beginning of query
$result = mysql_query($query);// execute query
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // step through results
   for ($i = 0; $i < $count{$row['part']}; $i++) { //if a part was scanned $count{$row['part']} times, display it that many times
   print $row['part']." ".$row['french']." / ".$row['length']." ".$row['plate']."(".$row['side'].")<br>";  //data parsing goes here. this will be expanded.
   };// close for loop
};//close while loop        
};//close else

?>
```

Comment: Stephen you want to be looking at the built query.  It is probably not totally correct.  Before iterating, check num_rows to see if you got results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
$query = "SELECT * FROM example"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
echo $row['name']. " - ". $row['age'];

?>
```

Courtesy of http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlfetcharray.php

You can also if you expect multiple results do:

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
$query = "SELECT * FROM example"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   echo $row['name']. " - ". $row['age'];
}


?>
```

Added code for your comment:

```
foreach ($scans as $currentscan) {
   $partselect = substr(mysql_real_escape_string($currentscan), 0, 5);
   $tempQuery .= "(part = ".$partselect." OR";
}//end foreach 
$tempQuery = substr($tempQuery,-2); //remove last OR 
$tempQuery .= ") ORDER BY side DESC, plate ASC LIMIT 1"; //add on end of query 
$query = "SELECT french, length, plate, side, type FROM parts WHERE ".$tempQuery;
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   //do something with row in result set... 
}
```

Comment: this isn't really what I'm looking for. updated with code sample to be more clear.

Comment: @stephen I updated your code, first built the query for all items in the $scans array and then loop over result set after...

Comment: This seems like it would work but the substr syntax doesnt seem right, because after that, $tempQuery = "R " (R and a blank space.)

Comment: @stephen updated the for loop it needs a .= for tempquery not a = which was why you were getting that bad value.

Comment: edited original post with the code as i'm running it and the error it throws. gonna go read up on mysql_fetch_array

Comment: Note that [`or die`](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) shouldn't be used when outputting HTML. You'll get invalid HTML. 
Also, database error messages shouldn't be displayed to non-admin users; doing so [discloses too much information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995351.aspx#securityerrormessages_topic2).

Answer (score 0):

Whay you should do is to construct a WHERE clause in PHP, which lets you select all rows that have any of the part numbers. Something like this:

```
$whereExpr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($scans); $i++) {
  $whereExpr[] = "part = \"{$scans[$i]}\"";
}

$whereExpr = implode(" OR ", $whereExpr);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `parts` WHERE $whereExpr ORDER BY <whatev>";

$result = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array) {
    $result[ $row['part'] ] = $row;
}
```

Comment: ooh. this creates one giganto query. I like this. trying it.

Comment: I would be careful if this is user generated content for the $whereExpr, as you're opening up your database to SQL injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Yeah, of course you should use mysql_real_escape_string and such. This was just some example code thrown together quickly.

Comment: this code is for an internal database application that will not be publicly usable, but yes, there will be escaping done.

Answer (score -1):

[MySQL Fetch Array Function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

After looking at your update/edit you could use the IN clause

```
// Represents your $scans array
$arr = array('Hello','World!','Beautiful','Day!');

foreach ($arr as $currentscan) {
    $partselect[] = substr(mysql_real_escape_string($currentscan), 0, 5);
}

$inExpr = implode("','",$partselect);

$query = "SELECT french, length, plate, side, type FROM parts WHERE part IN('$inExpr') ORDER BY side DESC";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print $partselect.' is a '.$row['french'].'/'.$row['length'].' - '.$row['type'].' - '.$row['plate'].'('.$row['side'].')<br \>';
}
```